# Leitura de strings e buffer de entrada

Tags: c, string, buffer

Sempre utilizei a função fgets() para ler strings do teclado, pois ela (ao menos eu achava isso) sempre limpa o buffer de entrada. Entretanto, estou encontrando alguns erros com a execução da função no caso do código abaixo. As strings não estão sendo lidas corretamente, é como se eu estivesse utilizando o scanf("%c") e captando lixo do buffer de entrada.
PS: Sei que o fflush(stdin) limpa o buffer de entrada, mas não gosto de utilizar essa função, pois ela não é portável.

A struct que eu estou pretendendo ler na função:

```
struct Participante
{
    char nome[40];
    char cpf[11];
    char email[20];
    char matricula[15];
    char nascimento[8];
    int ocupacao;
};
```

A função:

```
participante* entrada_dados()
{
    participante *part;
    char c;

    part = (participante*) malloc(sizeof(participante));

    printf("Digite o nome do participante \n");
    fgets(part->nome, sizeof(part->nome), stdin);

    printf("Digite o CPF do participante \n");
    fgets(part->cpf, sizeof(part->cpf), stdin);

    printf("Digite o email do participante \n");
    fgets(part->email, sizeof(part->email), stdin);

    printf("Digite a matricula do participante \n");
    fgets(part->matricula, sizeof(part->matricula), stdin);

    printf("Digite a data de nascimento do participante no formato DDMMAAAA \n");
    fgets(part->nascimento, sizeof(part->nascimento), stdin);

    printf("Digite a ocupacao do participante: \n 1- Professor \n 2- Estudante \n");
    scanf("%d", &part->ocupacao);

    return part;

}
```

Ps2: Estou utilizando ponteiro para estrutura, pois vou retornar o endereço alocado e utilizar para a construção de uma lista encadeada.

Exemplo da tela com o erro:

[image: Exemplo de tela com o erro]

Comment: Tens a chamada à função `entrada_dados()` num ciclo, certo?

Comment: Isso. Há um menu no main e enquanto informa a opção 1 a função entrada_dados() é chamada.

Comment: Você pode tentar limpar o buffer de entrada antes do primeiro `printf` da função `entra_dados()` com `fflush(stdin);`.

Answer (score 3):

Repara que nem todo o input é feito com `fgets()`.

A última parte, da ocupação do participante, é feita com `scanf()`. Não mistures `fgets()` com `scanf()`.

Se necessário usa `sscanf()`.

```
    char tmp[12];
    printf("Digite a ocupacao do participante: \n 1- Professor \n 2- Estudante \n");
    if (!fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin)) /* erro */;
    if (sscanf(tmp, "%d", &part->ocupacao) != 1) /* erro */;
```

Comment: O erro permanece ocorrendo, mesmo substituindo o scanf por essas linhas de código. Não entendi exatamente qual o problema de misturar fgets() e scanf(). De toda forma, obrigado por responder.

Comment: Como tu próprio dizes: `fgets()` "limpa o buffer de entrada". Ao misturares esta função com `scanf()` (que não limpa o buffer de entrada) terás de gerir o buffer de entrada manualmente. Verifica se o resto do teu código está livre de funções que não limpam o buffer de entrada. Verifica sempre o valor devolvido pelas funções para detecção de erros.

Answer (score -1):

é muito simples vou dar uma dica que utilizo bastante`

```
 struct participante{
char nome[40];
char cpf[11];
char email[20];
char matricula[15];
char nascimento[8];
int ocupacao;}; 
struct participante part;
void p()
{
printf("Digite o nome do participante \n");
scanf("%s",part.nome);

printf("Digite o CPF do participante \n");
scanf("%s",part.cpf);

printf("Digite o email do participante \n");
scanf("%s",part.email);

printf("Digite a matricula do participante \n");
scanf("%s",part.matricula);

printf("Digite a data de nascimento do participante no formato DDMMAAAA \n");
scanf("%s",part.nascimento);

printf("Digite a ocupacao do participante: \n 1- Professor \n 2- Estudante \n");
scanf("%d",&part.ocupacao);

// não precisa dar return pois é só declara a struct como global
}
int main()
{

    p();


}
```

ta ai acabei de testar, e esta funcionado corretamente
sempre utilizo isso nos meus códigos com struct
qualquer dúvida estou aqui